# Back button behavior on an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have a problem in my app. I have a MainActivity with Fragments, each Fragment have a list with a recyclerView. When I click an Item of the list, the app goes to a new DetailActivity.

In the DetailActivity I have the next code line:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

When I click the back button in the ActionBar I return to the MainActivity in another fragment, not the one I clicked the item.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you are not terminating the parent activity when launching the detailActivity 
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @kareem adel make sure you are not ending the previous activity. Dont use Flag_activity_clear_task or flag_activity_new_task

If that doesn't help you could just tell the back button where to go.

With getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); set you can do this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(id == android.R.id.home){
            //Back button was hit so go somewhere.
            Intent i= new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //Clear previous Activities 
            startActivity(i);
            finish(); //End this activity.
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```